# How to transform an input xml(three inputs) into ouput xml(two ouputs)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have input xml with three fields  (title, artist,  country), I want an ouput xml with two fields(title and artist(concatenated), address(exchnaged with country) after transformation, Can any one help me to write a transformation xslt.

**Input xml:**

```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <catalog>
            <cd>
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <country>USA</country>
                
            </cd>
            <cd>
                <title>Hide your heart</title>
                <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
                <country>UK</country>
               
            </cd>
            <cd>
                <title>Greatest Hits</title>
                <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
                <country>USA</country>
               
            </cd>
            <cd>
                <title>Still got the blues</title>
                <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
                <country>UK</country>
                
            </cd>
            <cd>
                <title>Eros</title>
                <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
                <country>EU</country> 
            </cd>
        </catalog>
```

**Required output:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title_and_artist>Empire Burlesque by Bob Dylan</title_and_artist>
            <address>USA</address>
            
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title_and_artist>Hide your heart by Bonnie Tyler</title_and_artist>
            <address>UK</address>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title_and_artist>Greatest Hits by Dolly Parton</title_and_artist>
            <address>USA</address>  
        </cd> 
    </catalog>
```

**The xslt I used**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements=""/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(title, ' ' ,'by',' ', artist) "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="address/node()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(title, ' ' ,'by',' ', artist)
   "/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="address/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <xsl:copy>
      <title_and_artist>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(title, ' ' ,'by',' ', artist)  "/>
      </title_and_artist>
      <address>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
      </address>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```